# Replace text with HTML in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, syntax-highlighting

I'm attempting to write a an add-on for Google Docs using Google App Script that performs syntax highlighting. I'm using hightlight.js to perform the highlighting on the selected text and attempted to replace the selected text with formatted text. Is there a way to just insert the HTML returned from highlight.js, or do I need to do something more to format the text properly for Google Docs?

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this? I am having a similar requirement to render HTML String text in google docs.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot insert HTML "as" Google Docs (AFAIK). You can insert it as regular text, but the tags will be shown, etc, just like when you view a page source.

Google Docs have its own "DOM" structure and you'd have to "parse" your HTML into Docs' format. Appending paragraphs and text elements and setting their [attributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute). It's going to be a bit cumbersome to do, but is surely possible.

Another possibility is to upload the HTML to Google Drive and set the `convert` flag, letting Google Drive do this hard task for you. Then you grab the resulting Doc and append/replace it to the current document you're working on, a much easier task (but it's not a single-line code). The down-side is that it'll take that much longer for your Add-On to retrieve the value. You'd have to test it to see if that's acceptable.